# Get Xpath results on 13 digits length (website crawling)

Tags: xpath, string-length

i am searching a way to get the 13 digit (EAN) code of the following code:

```
`<dl>
              <dt>Merk:</dt>
        <dd>Keddoc</dd>
                              <dt>Soort hondensnack:</dt>
          <dd>Trainers / snoepjes<br>
Zachte snacks</dd>
                              <dt>Referentie: </dt>
        <dd>87212</dd>
                    <dt>EAN: </dt>
        <dd>8720153872126</dd>
        </dl>`
```

The  tag doesn't have any attribute to search on. So therefore i think i either need to find based on a xpath code which gives the value of the following DD tag after the "EAN:" dt tag or a xpath which finds each code with a 13 digit string. Is there a way to do so?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$ xidel -se '//dl/dd[matches(text(), "^\d{13}$")]' file.html
8720153872126
```

or

```
$ xidel -se '//dt[contains(text(), "EAN:")]/following-sibling::dd' file.html
8720153872126
```